# What is the simplest proof about this differentiation property?

Tags: derivatives

What is the simplest proof about this differentiation property: $\frac{d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\left(x^2-1\right)^n = (2n)!$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand the binomial,
$$
(x^2-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} x^{2k}(-1)^{n-k}.
$$
With the exception of $k=n $, all terms have degree less than $2n $ and so
$$
\frac {d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}\, (x^2-1)^n=\frac {d^{2n}}{dx^{2n}}{n\choose n}x^{2n}= (2n)!.
$$